# Sublime Text 3 + LatexTool unintentional new window after compilation

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text 3 + LatexTool on Windows 10 to edit my Tex files. Recently, after an update of Sublime Text, I find that there will be an untitled new window of sublime each time I use Ctrl+B to compile my tex codes. Are there any possible causes for this annoying issue?

Answer (score 5):

Follow the fix here: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1530

In short,
Go into the LaTeX Tools settings (Preferences → Package Settings → LaTeXTools → Settings – User)
Find the setting "windows" → "sublime_exectuable" and set it to "subl.exe"

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported a few times in relation to the [LaTeXing](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXing) package and affects [LaTeXTools](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LaTeXTools) as well.

Both packages include the ability to send the focus back to Sublime after generating an external file, and the method by which they're doing it is causing your issue here. The ultimate source of the problem is that the packages are trying to give the focus back using the wrong program, which causes it to create extra windows that you don't want.

In particular, they try to find and execute `subl` or `sublime_text` to send the focus back, in that order; if `subl` can't be found, `sublime_text` is executed instead.

These two programs are not the same thing; `subl` will focus an existing instance of Sublime and start one if there isn't one running, while `sublime_text` will always create a new window.

The most expedient fix is to go into the preferences for the package and set `keep_focus` to `false` (this applies to both packages), although this will stop it from being able to give the focus back to Sublime automatically.

Alternatively, you can follow the directions for setting up Sublime's [Command Line Interface](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html), which will make sure that `subl` is available on the system `PATH` so that it can be found and used to return the focus, which should resolve the problem while keeping the focus functionality.